# Javascript: Number() function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, selenium

Okay, so I'm trying to get the 10 out of `<span class="totalcount">10</span>`and then convert it to a number. My code should return `number Converted total: 10` but it instead returns `undefined Converted total: undefined`. What am I doing wrong?
My code is as follows.

```
  var begtotal = driver.findElement(element).getText().then(function(begtotal){
    var total = Number(begtotal);
  }).then(function(total) {
    console.log(typeof total + ' Converted total: ' + total);
  });
```

I have tried using parseInt() in place of Number(), but I get the same results.

Comment: You aren’t returning anything from `function (begtotal) { … }`, just declaring a variable. (Not much reason to chain another `then` there, though – put the `console.log` in the same function.)

Comment: Neither `parseInt(arg)` or `Number(arg)` return *undefined* for any value of *arg*, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Replace `var total = Number(begtotal);` with `return Number(begtotal);`

Comment: by the way, that is unnecessarily confusing code, having `var begtotal =` ... and then `function(begtotal)` in the `.then` ... I would recommend writing code that is not so ambiguous :p

Comment: Thanks Ryan and Chris, your solution worked. Sorry about my code being kinda awful. I literally just started using Javascript last week, my team for some unknown reason decided it'd be a good idea to use a language literally no-one in the team knows for a project.